# Construct a function which is in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ but not $L^q(B_{a,b})$ for any $a,b>0$, $q>p$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

By trying on my own, I just find $f(x) = |x|^{-\frac{d}{p}}(|log|x||+1)^{-\frac{2}{p}}\chi_{B_{0,1}}$ is a function in $L^p(\mathbb{R^d})$ but not in $L^{q}(B_{0,r})$. How can I modify this function to get a desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take a countable dense subset $\{q_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and sum up scaled versions of your $f$, translated by $q_n$.

Comment: Oh I got it. let $\{q_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ have enumeration and take $f_n = (|x|-q_n)^{-\frac{d}{p}}(|\log (|x|-q_n)|+1)^{-\frac{2}{p}})\chi_{B_{0,1}}$, and let $f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}f_n$, and I have a desired result. Thanks.